# dill.dump_session won't work in jupyter lab

Tags: python, cython, jupyter-lab, dill

I want to start working on jupyter lab instead of spyder but i have a problem. I can't save the variables in my workspace.

I am trying to use jupyter lab to run a code like this:

```
import dill
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.arange(1,300), 'B': np.arange(2,301)})
STRIN = 'A'
aa = 34

dill.dump_session('filename.p')
```

And I get the following error:

```
TypeError: no default __reduce__ due to non-trivial __cinit__
```

And the full trace back is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-613d82353bf4> in <module>
----> 1 dill.dump_session('filename.p')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py in dump_session(filename, main, byref, **kwds)
    349         pickler._recurse = False # disable pickling recursion for globals
    350         pickler._session = True  # is best indicator of when pickling a session
--> 351         pickler.dump(main)
    352     finally:
    353         if f is not filename:  # If newly opened file

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py in dump(self, obj)
    443             raise PicklingError(msg)
    444         else:
--> 445             StockPickler.dump(self, obj)
    446         stack.clear()  # clear record of 'recursion-sensitive' pickled objects
    447         return

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in dump(self, obj)
    435         if self.proto >= 4:
    436             self.framer.start_framing()
--> 437         self.save(obj)
    438         self.write(STOP)
    439         self.framer.end_framing()

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    502         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    503         if f is not None:
--> 504             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    505             return
    506 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py in save_module(pickler, obj)
   1293                 + ["__builtins__", "__loader__"]]
   1294             pickler.save_reduce(_import_module, (obj.__name__,), obj=obj,
-> 1295                                 state=_main_dict)
   1296             log.info("# M1")
   1297         else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save_reduce(self, func, args, state, listitems, dictitems, obj)
    660 
    661         if state is not None:
--> 662             save(state)
    663             write(BUILD)
    664 

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    502         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    503         if f is not None:
--> 504             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    505             return
    506 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py in save_module_dict(pickler, obj)
    910             # we only care about session the first pass thru
    911             pickler._session = False
--> 912         StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
    913         log.info("# D2")
    914     return

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save_dict(self, obj)
    857 
    858         self.memoize(obj)
--> 859         self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
    860 
    861     dispatch[dict] = save_dict

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in _batch_setitems(self, items)
    883                 for k, v in tmp:
    884                     save(k)
--> 885                     save(v)
    886                 write(SETITEMS)
    887             elif n:

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    547 
    548         # Save the reduce() output and finally memoize the object
--> 549         self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
    550 
    551     def persistent_id(self, obj):

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save_reduce(self, func, args, state, listitems, dictitems, obj)
    660 
    661         if state is not None:
--> 662             save(state)
    663             write(BUILD)
    664 

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    502         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    503         if f is not None:
--> 504             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    505             return
    506 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py in save_module_dict(pickler, obj)
    910             # we only care about session the first pass thru
    911             pickler._session = False
--> 912         StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
    913         log.info("# D2")
    914     return

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save_dict(self, obj)
    857 
    858         self.memoize(obj)
--> 859         self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
    860 
    861     dispatch[dict] = save_dict

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in _batch_setitems(self, items)
    883                 for k, v in tmp:
    884                     save(k)
--> 885                     save(v)
    886                 write(SETITEMS)
    887             elif n:

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    547 
    548         # Save the reduce() output and finally memoize the object
--> 549         self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
    550 
    551     def persistent_id(self, obj):

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save_reduce(self, func, args, state, listitems, dictitems, obj)
    660 
    661         if state is not None:
--> 662             save(state)
    663             write(BUILD)
    664 

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    502         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    503         if f is not None:
--> 504             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    505             return
    506 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py in save_module_dict(pickler, obj)
    910             # we only care about session the first pass thru
    911             pickler._session = False
--> 912         StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
    913         log.info("# D2")
    914     return

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save_dict(self, obj)
    857 
    858         self.memoize(obj)
--> 859         self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
    860 
    861     dispatch[dict] = save_dict

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in _batch_setitems(self, items)
    883                 for k, v in tmp:
    884                     save(k)
--> 885                     save(v)
    886                 write(SETITEMS)
    887             elif n:

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    502         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    503         if f is not None:
--> 504             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    505             return
    506 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py in save_module_dict(pickler, obj)
    910             # we only care about session the first pass thru
    911             pickler._session = False
--> 912         StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
    913         log.info("# D2")
    914     return

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save_dict(self, obj)
    857 
    858         self.memoize(obj)
--> 859         self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
    860 
    861     dispatch[dict] = save_dict

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in _batch_setitems(self, items)
    883                 for k, v in tmp:
    884                     save(k)
--> 885                     save(v)
    886                 write(SETITEMS)
    887             elif n:

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    547 
    548         # Save the reduce() output and finally memoize the object
--> 549         self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
    550 
    551     def persistent_id(self, obj):

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save_reduce(self, func, args, state, listitems, dictitems, obj)
    660 
    661         if state is not None:
--> 662             save(state)
    663             write(BUILD)
    664 

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    502         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    503         if f is not None:
--> 504             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    505             return
    506 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py in save_module_dict(pickler, obj)
    910             # we only care about session the first pass thru
    911             pickler._session = False
--> 912         StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
    913         log.info("# D2")
    914     return

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save_dict(self, obj)
    857 
    858         self.memoize(obj)
--> 859         self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
    860 
    861     dispatch[dict] = save_dict

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in _batch_setitems(self, items)
    883                 for k, v in tmp:
    884                     save(k)
--> 885                     save(v)
    886                 write(SETITEMS)
    887             elif n:

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    502         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    503         if f is not None:
--> 504             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    505             return
    506 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py in save_module_dict(pickler, obj)
    910             # we only care about session the first pass thru
    911             pickler._session = False
--> 912         StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
    913         log.info("# D2")
    914     return

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save_dict(self, obj)
    857 
    858         self.memoize(obj)
--> 859         self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
    860 
    861     dispatch[dict] = save_dict

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in _batch_setitems(self, items)
    883                 for k, v in tmp:
    884                     save(k)
--> 885                     save(v)
    886                 write(SETITEMS)
    887             elif n:

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    547 
    548         # Save the reduce() output and finally memoize the object
--> 549         self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
    550 
    551     def persistent_id(self, obj):

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save_reduce(self, func, args, state, listitems, dictitems, obj)
    660 
    661         if state is not None:
--> 662             save(state)
    663             write(BUILD)
    664 

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    502         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    503         if f is not None:
--> 504             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    505             return
    506 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py in save_module_dict(pickler, obj)
    910             # we only care about session the first pass thru
    911             pickler._session = False
--> 912         StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
    913         log.info("# D2")
    914     return

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save_dict(self, obj)
    857 
    858         self.memoize(obj)
--> 859         self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
    860 
    861     dispatch[dict] = save_dict

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in _batch_setitems(self, items)
    888                 k, v = tmp[0]
    889                 save(k)
--> 890                 save(v)
    891                 write(SETITEM)
    892             # else tmp is empty, and we're done

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    547 
    548         # Save the reduce() output and finally memoize the object
--> 549         self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
    550 
    551     def persistent_id(self, obj):

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save_reduce(self, func, args, state, listitems, dictitems, obj)
    660 
    661         if state is not None:
--> 662             save(state)
    663             write(BUILD)
    664 

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    502         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    503         if f is not None:
--> 504             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    505             return
    506 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py in save_module_dict(pickler, obj)
    910             # we only care about session the first pass thru
    911             pickler._session = False
--> 912         StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
    913         log.info("# D2")
    914     return

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save_dict(self, obj)
    857 
    858         self.memoize(obj)
--> 859         self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
    860 
    861     dispatch[dict] = save_dict

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in _batch_setitems(self, items)
    883                 for k, v in tmp:
    884                     save(k)
--> 885                     save(v)
    886                 write(SETITEMS)
    887             elif n:

~\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    522             reduce = getattr(obj, "__reduce_ex__", None)
    523             if reduce is not None:
--> 524                 rv = reduce(self.proto)
    525             else:
    526                 reduce = getattr(obj, "__reduce__", None)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\socket.cp37-win_amd64.pyd in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.__reduce_cython__()

TypeError: no default __reduce__ due to non-trivial __cinit__
```

What can I do to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please include the full traceback. If I had to hazard a guess some pandas type doesn't have a `__reduce__` implementation that `dill` is expecting, hard to say for sure without the full traceback. If you really need to do this I doubt it will be possible without patching some downstream library you don't control.

Comment: it actually happens also if i want to save just simple variables like integers and strings. i added the traceback. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like dill is trying to pickle a zmq socket, which is happening because of the jupyter environment’s hooks into your session. See e.g. https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/issues/132#issuecomment-501906583 and https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/255.

I bet if you tried to do this outside of jupyter it would work.

I guess dill could probably do more to detect that it’s being run inside jupyter and avoid this but that doesn’t seem to be how it works at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

IPython and ipykernel packages have issues with serializing socket objects. These objects need to be filtered out. Execute the following code to reset the dictionary and achieve the desired persistence:

```
from dill._dill import register
from dill._dill import save_module_dict

@register(dict)
def snb_save_module_dict(pickler, obj):
  keys=list(obj.keys())
  for k in keys:
    if type(obj[k]).__module__.startswith("ipykernel.") or type(obj[k]).__module__.startswith("IPython."):
      obj.pop(k,None)
    else:
      pass
      #print(k,obj[k])
  save_module_dict(pickler, obj)
```